# Calculate asymptotic limit for log(n) + Ө( sqrt(n))

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Assuming `f(n) = Ө(sqrt(n))`.

By the definition of **Big-theta** Ө, we can say: There exists two constants `c1` and `c2`, both real positive numbers such that: `c1*sqrt(n) <= f(n) <= c2*sqrt(n)`

So, we have the following sum:  `log(n) + f(n)`.

I was thinking about writing `log(n)` as `Ө(log(n))`.

So, the sum would be `Ө(sqrt(n))` by considering `Ө(sqrt(n))` is greater than `Ө(log(n))`, 
but I still don't get how can I calculate an asymptotic limit here.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly `sqrt(n)` dominates `log(n)` when `n` tends to infinity.

So, the asymptotic limit for `log(n) + Ө(sqrt(n))` tends to just `Ө(sqrt(n))`      since
`log(n) = o(sqrt(n))`.

By example: let `log` be decimal logarithm, then

```
n = 1,         log (n) = 0,   sqrt (n) = 1

n = 100,       log (n) = 2,   sqrt (n) = 10

n = 10000,     log (n) = 4,   sqrt (n) = 100

n = 1000000,   log (n) = 6,   sqrt (n) = 1000

n = 100000000, log (n) = 8,   sqrt (n) = 10000
```

etc.